# How can I calculate the total number of unique solutions for the n queen puzzle?

Tags: polynomials, puzzle

Constructing a fairly optimized algorithm for finding all the possible solutions for the [n queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Sample_program) puzzle is fairly easy, at least for up to 20 queens.

Is there a way though to calculate the number of distinct solutions, as well as as the number of fundamental positions without actually waiting for the algorithm to finish and then counting those solutions?

Comment: No closed-form formula seems to be known, see http://oeis.org/A000170 ; the OEIS entry does not even give any asymptotic formulae, though it gives a conjecture: "Strong conjecture: there is a constant c around 2.54 such that a(n) is asymptotic to n!/c^n". Apparently the solution count has only been computed for $n \leq 26$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of solutions $a(n)$ to the $n$-queen problem is the content of [OEIS A000710](http://oeis.org/A000170). In particular, no closed-form formula seems to be known, but the OEIS entry includes an conjecture attributed to [Benoit Cloitre](http://bcmathematics.monsite-orange.fr/):

> There is a constant $c$ around $2.54$ such that $a(n)$ is asymptotic to $$\frac{n!}{c^n} .$$

Apparently [$a(n)$ has only been computed for $n \leq 26$](http://oeis.org/A000170/b000170.txt).

For a detailed and relatively recent survey, see

> Bell, J., and Stevens, B. "[A survey of known results and research areas for $n$-queens [PDF]](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0012365X07010394/1-s2.0-S0012365X07010394-main.pdf?_tid=789c6074-759b-11e5-a018-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1445174811_0a405d0610d8b34dc50f75967708c1e5)." *Discrete Mathematics* 309 (2009), pp. 1–31.

Comment: After reading your material, it seems that what I originally thought is true, there is no way of exactly computing it. This is still interesting material though, thanks.

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be quite difficult. As you probably know, this is radically different from the $n$-rook problem, which could be solved by a clever elementary school student. (And you're welcome, I'm glad you found it interesting.)